# SQL IF-Statment within funciton

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I've been working with SQL lately to make ends meet with my programming. I am trying to create a function which does a select, and if it views any duplicates (>1) of the same Analyte, it will create a string.

For example, If the select statement pulls back `apples, oranges, peanuts, grapes, grapes, peaches, oranges, pineapple` I will obtain a string of `oranges,grapes`. However if the there are no duplicates, the system breaks with an error since I'm trying to use a sub-string call on nothing.

How can I use an IF-Statment to make it pass back "NORECS" if result is still empty, and to use the sub-string functionality if it is not empty?

Working code which breaks if select doesn't pull duplicates:

```
Declare @result varchar(1000)

set @result = ''

select @result = @result + R.ANALYTE + ','
 FROM results R (NOLOCK)    
    left join tests T (NOLOCK) on (T.testcode = R.testcode)

where 
T.SHOW='Y' and R.SA='Show'
and R.ID = 3094083
group by R.ANALYTE
having COUNT(*)>1

select substring(@result, 1, len(@result) - 1) AS MissingAnas
```

Attempted IF-Statement which does the "Else" regardless.

```
    Declare @result varchar(1000)

    set @result = ''

    select @result = @result + R.ANALYTE + ','
     FROM results R (NOLOCK)    
        left join tests T (NOLOCK) on (T.testcode = R.testcode)

    where 
    T.SHOW='Y' and R.SA='Show'
    and R.ID = 3094083
    group by R.ANALYTE
    having COUNT(*)>1

    if (Count(@result)>1)
    Begin
    select substring(@result, 1, len(@result) - 1) AS MissingAnas
    End
    Else
    Begin
    set @result = 'NORECS'
    select @result AS MissingAnas
    End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use RETURN Statement in below format :

Declare @result varchar(1000)

set @result = ''

select @result = @result + R.ANALYTE + ','
 FROM results R (NOLOCK)    
    left join tests T (NOLOCK) on (T.testcode = R.testcode)

where 
T.SHOW='Y' and R.SA='Show'
and R.ID = 3094083
group by R.ANALYTE
having COUNT(*)>1

if (Count(@result)>1)
Begin
   SET @result = substring(@result, 1, len(@result) - 1) 
End
Else
Begin
   SET @result = 'NORECS'
End

SELECT @result
```

Comment: this still passes back only the "Else" statement of 'NORECS'. when there is a duplicate string of `oranges,grapes`.

Comment: I figured it out. Its because COUNT is being used instead of LEN

Answer (score 2):

You are going through all of this trouble to remove the last comma, and there are a couple of ways around that.

One is using a different concatenation with the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select @result = stuff((
  select ',' + r.analyte
  from results R (nolock)    
    left join tests T (nolock) 
      on T.testcode = R.testcode
  where T.show='Y' 
    and R.sa='show'
    and R.id = 3094083
  group by R.analyte
  having count(*)>1
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')
```

Then if `@result` is still an empty string (since you set it as one in the beginning), change the value to 'NORECS' using `coalesce()` and `nullif()`

```
set @result = coalesce(nullif(@result,''),'NORECS');
```

When using the `for xml path('')` version, you do not need to `set @result = ''` before concatenating. So if `@result` is `null` instead of `''` to start iwth, the final coalesce can be simplified to:

```
set @result = coalesce(@result,'NORECS');
```

---

Regarding your use of `nolock` everywhere, you might want to reconsider your reasons behind doing that.

- [Bad Habits: Putting NOLOCK everywhere - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: can you please expand what the `,1,2,''` represents within `for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'')` ? I noticed that for a single analyte, it cuts off a letter. Moving the 2 to a 1 fixed this issue, however am a bit confused why.

Comment: @Brad My mistake, it should have be `1,1,''`. They are the parameters for the `stuff()` function, which with those parameters starting from position 1, replaces the first 1 character(s), with `''`.